HttpWebRequest throws 'Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream' error when reading API response
I'm working on an application that fetches country data from the API https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all using HttpWebRequest. The code was working fine a few weeks ago, but now it throws the following error:

System.IO.IOException: 'Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.'

This error occurs when calling responseStream.ReadToEnd() to read the response body. I haven't made any changes to the code, so I'm unsure why this is happening.
Here is the code I'm using:
public class CountryRepository
{
    private List<Country> _Countries = new List<Country>();

    private string url = "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all";

    public List<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        string json = CallRestMethod(url);
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json); // Parse JSON

        foreach (JObject item in jsonArray)
        {
            _Countries.Add(new Country
            {
                Code = (string)item["cca2"],
                Name = (string)item["name"]?["common"],
                Capital = item["capital"] != null && item["capital"].Type == JTokenType.Array
                    ? (string)item["capital"].First
                    : null,
                Population = (int)(item["population"] ?? 0),
                Area = item["area"]?.Type == JTokenType.Null ? 0 : (float)(item["area"]),
                Region = (string)item["region"],
            });
        }

        return _Countries;
    }

    public static string CallRestMethod(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        using (StreamReader responseStream = new
        StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            string result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            webResponse.Close();
            return result;
        }
    }
}

I've verified the API endpoint in Postman (it works fine there).
Increased timeout values and set KeepAlive = false.
When I copied the URL and opened it, it gave me:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 477495 of the JSON data"

if that's connected to the problem.
What could cause this error when reading the response stream from HttpWebRequest?

Why are you using HttpWebRequest anyway. it's deprecated. Use HttpClient instead.

I have to use that, it's for school projects and it's said to use that.

Tell "school projects" they don't know what they're talking about. The docs clearly state "WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete, and you shouldn't use them for new development. Use HttpClient instead."

I will, but for now I need it sadly, I made the project 3 weeks ago and it worked, today I tried to run it again and it's not working. Is there any fix for that or I need to use HttpClient?

Either way the only way to know for sure what's going on is to use a transparent proxy such as Fiddler to check working and non-working requests, compare them and see what you're missing. Probably some header or something. Also why use JArray why not deserialize directly to Country using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Weirdly I can replicate this in a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/JlyvgU but not on my machine. TLS verion seems to make no difference, nor does .NET 8 or 9. It does seem to be a TLS issue though.

Seems to be a general issue on their side - based on their latest ticket:
https://gitlab.com/restcountries/restcountries/-/issues/239
I was able to reduce the response by using filters and it seems to work again - might be a temporary solution for you.
